# Time Machine connection error with Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, mac, time-machine, ubuntu-server, netatalk

I've set up a home server with Ubuntu in software RAID 1 to save my Mac files with Time Machine. The backup partition in the server shows up in the Time Machine menu, but at the time of conecting it gives the following error:

```
"There was an error connecting to the server "servidor". Check the server name 
or IP address, and then try again.

If you are unable to resolve the problem contact your system administrator"
```

It is my first time making a RAID array and using Netatalk, and I am not a Linux expert.
This is the way it is set up:

I mounted a RAID 1 like this, it is formated in ext4:

```
sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/TimeMachine
```

I followed [this manual](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811541) to set Netatalk, exactly the same but changing 'username' for 'jorge' (my username).

Maybe some of you guys know what I'm doing wrong, and sorry if I made gramatical mistakes, I'm not native ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are likely more descriptive error messages in /var/log/system.log, which would help identify the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Update: this is apparently a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netatalk/+bug/810732

The solution seems to simply use

```
- -tcp -noddp -uamlist uams_dhx.so,uams_dhx2_passwd.so
```

on **/etc/netatalk/afpd.conf**

This will not allow guest users, but works well otherwise, with Time Machine and everything.

Comment: Could you maybe expand on how his is done? What do you mean with "use on /etc/netatalk/afpd.conf"

I have the same problem and in the bototm of the `afpd.conf`this line is commented out. I tried to remove the comment and then restarted netatalk. But it didn't work

Comment: I'm sorry, @MånsDahlström, I haven't tried this myself, and my own `netatalk` configuration is quite different from what I posted (literally) a decade ago. [This old tutorial for `netatalk` on Ubuntu](https://www.rudiswiki.de/wiki9/ServerUbuntu1204#Setup_netatalk) just says: 'append that line to `afpd.conf`'. You can also take a look at the [`man` page for `afpd.conf`](https://netatalk.sourceforge.io/2.0/htmldocs/afpd.conf.5.html) which pretty much says the same. And it's quite possible that the required libraries (`uams_dhx.so`,`uams_dhx2_passwd.so`) may not be installed on your system...

Comment: ... and before you ask, no, I have no idea how these are installed :) Since Apple abandoned its own AFP in favour of SMB (Samba), I never bothered with `netatalk` ever again, although it still has a community that continues to publish new versions and security updates (as late as March 2022, which is quite recent at the time of writing this comment!) at https://netatalk.sourceforge.io/ — you can also get links to their Wiki there, as well as to the available support channels (mostly via their mailing list).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Apparently afpd crashes when a user successfully authenticates.

Maybe the following logs are useful:

```
Aug 16 04:50:14 rivendell avahi-daemon[26344]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::5604:a6ff:fe9d:5e22.
Aug 16 04:50:14 rivendell avahi-daemon[26344]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Aug 16 04:50:14 rivendell avahi-daemon[26344]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 10.69.69.169.
Aug 16 04:50:14 rivendell avahi-daemon[26344]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Aug 16 04:50:14 rivendell avahi-daemon[26344]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Aug 16 04:50:14 rivendell avahi-daemon[26344]: Registering new address record for fe80::5604:a6ff:fe9d:5e22 on eth0.*.
Aug 16 04:50:14 rivendell avahi-daemon[26344]: Registering new address record for 10.69.69.169 on eth0.IPv4.
Aug 16 04:50:14 rivendell avahi-daemon[26344]: Registering HINFO record with values 'X86_64'/'LINUX'.
Aug 16 04:50:15 rivendell avahi-daemon[26344]: Server startup complete. Host name is rivendell.local. Local service cookie is 829140687.
Aug 16 04:50:16 rivendell avahi-daemon[26344]: Service "rivendell" (/services/afpd.service) successfully established.
Aug 16 04:50:27 rivendell afpd[26349]: AFP3.3 Login by nobody
Aug 16 04:50:27 rivendell afpd[26349]: volume "Home Directory" does not support Extended Attributes, using ea:ad instead
Aug 16 04:50:31 rivendell afpd[26349]: AFP logout by nobody
Aug 16 04:50:31 rivendell afpd[26349]: dsi_stream_read: len:0, unexpected EOF
Aug 16 04:50:31 rivendell afpd[26349]: afp_over_dsi: client logged out, terminating DSI session
Aug 16 04:50:31 rivendell afpd[26349]: AFP statistics: 0.14 KB read, 0.12 KB written
Aug 16 04:50:39 rivendell afpd[26352]: ===============================================================
Aug 16 04:50:39 rivendell afpd[26352]: INTERNAL ERROR: Signal 11 in pid 26352 (2.2.1)
Aug 16 04:50:39 rivendell afpd[26352]: ===============================================================
Aug 16 04:50:39 rivendell afpd[26352]: BACKTRACE: 3 stack frames:
Aug 16 04:50:39 rivendell afpd[26352]:  #0 /usr/sbin/afpd(netatalk_panic+0x1c) [0x7fdd6c1d3aec]
Aug 16 04:50:39 rivendell afpd[26352]:  #1 /usr/sbin/afpd(+0x50bec) [0x7fdd6c1d3bec]
Aug 16 04:50:39 rivendell afpd[26352]:  #2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x364c0) [0x7fdd6b1904c0]
Aug 16 04:50:45 rivendell afpd[26356]: AFP3.3 Login by nobody
Aug 16 04:50:45 rivendell afpd[26356]: volume "Home Directory" does not support Extended Attributes, using ea:ad instead
Aug 16 04:51:27 rivendell afpd[26367]: ===============================================================
Aug 16 04:51:27 rivendell afpd[26367]: INTERNAL ERROR: Signal 11 in pid 26367 (2.2.1)
Aug 16 04:51:27 rivendell afpd[26367]: ===============================================================
Aug 16 04:51:27 rivendell afpd[26367]: BACKTRACE: 3 stack frames:
Aug 16 04:51:27 rivendell afpd[26367]:  #0 /usr/sbin/afpd(netatalk_panic+0x1c) [0x7fdd6c1d3aec]
Aug 16 04:51:27 rivendell afpd[26367]:  #1 /usr/sbin/afpd(+0x50bec) [0x7fdd6c1d3bec]
Aug 16 04:51:27 rivendell afpd[26367]:  #2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x364c0) [0x7fdd6b1904c0]
```